# Taking photo always returns RESULT_CANCELED (0) in onActivityResult(..)

Tags: android, android-camera, firebase-storage

I trying to build [storage app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage) using firebase storage sample app, and when I take a picture I always get RESUL_CANCELED in onActivityResult(..).
Here is the code:

```
@AfterPermissionGranted(RC_STORAGE_PERMS)
private void launchCamera() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "launchCamera");

    // Check that we have permission to read images from external storage.
    String perm = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    if (!EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perm)) {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.rationale_storage),
                RC_STORAGE_PERMS, perm);
        return;
    }

    // Choose file storage location, must be listed in res/xml/file_paths.xml
    File externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(externalDir, "photos/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");

    // Create content:// URI for file, required since Android N
    // See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html
    mFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
           "com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage.fileprovider", file);

    // Create and launch the intent
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, RC_TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);
    if (requestCode == RC_TAKE_PICTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (mFileUri != null) {
                uploadFromUri(mFileUri);
            } else {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "File URI is null");
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Taking picture failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

logs: onActivityResult:101:0:Intent { }

Comment: Try a different camera app. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementations have [a history of bugs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html). Also, don't forget to put `mFileUri` in your saved instance state `Bundle`, as your process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, that was the issue. So it depends from the version of the Android?

Comment: @madim what exactly was the problem, I'm experiencing the same issue on Android 12, Samsung Galaxy S21, OneUi version 4.0.
Was it the need to save instance state, or the camera app???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So it depends from the version of the Android?

That depends on what you mean by that and what the bug is.

As I noted in my comment, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementations have [a history of bugs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html). There is a wide range of such bugs, not necessarily tied to Android OS version.

However, your code takes an interesting approach to `EXTRA_OUTPUT`: using `FileProvider` with a location on external storage. Long-term, `FileProvider` is a fine answer, as [Android N is starting to ban `file:` `Uri` values](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html). However, there are many camera apps that will have problems with `content:` `Uri` values, because the developers of those camera apps did not expect such values. For example, Google's own Camera app fails for `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` on `content:` `Uri` values, at least as of a couple of months ago, though it is fine for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Worse, there is no way for an app to advertise what schemes it supports for an extra. With the "data" facet of an `Intent`, the `<intent-filter>` can advertise supported schemes, but that does not work for extras. So, when you invoke `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with a `content:` `Uri` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you are not limited to camera apps that happen to support `content:` `Uri` values.

You might consider temporarily dropping your `targetSdkVersion` below 24, then using `Uri.fromFile(file)` instead of `FileProvider.getUriForFile(...)`, and see what happens. If your original camera app works fine, then that app does not support `content:` `Uri` values correctly, and that was what caused your original problem.

Overall, I recommend that developers using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` keep their `targetSdkVersion` below 24 and use `file:` `Uri` values for a few years, until such time as a higher percentage of users have a camera app installed that supports `content:` `Uri` values. Or, offer your users a choice between their existing camera apps (via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`) and some camera capability that you build into your own app (e.g., using [my library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2)), to increase the odds that *something* will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some code invoking a smooth workaround adding to @CommonsWare.
Checking API and handling appropriately worked great.

```
   private void startCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = ImgUtils.createTempImageFile(this);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            mTempPhotoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {

            //create Uri with 'file://' prefix 
                tempImgUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            }else{

            //create Uri with 'content://' prefix 
                tempImgUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY,
                        photoFile);
            }
            mImgUriString = tempImgUri.toString();

            // Add the URI so the camera can store the image
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempImgUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```